# Can You Configure Mathematica to Not Abort?

Tags: manipulate, export, abort

So I am playing around with an interpolation polynomial. The code for what I am trying to do is computationally heavy:

`p[x_, n_]:=Sum[f[Table[15*(k/n),{k,0,n}][[i]]]*Product[Piecewise[{{(x-Table[15*(k/n),{k, 0, n}][[j]])/(Table[15*(k/n),{k,0,n}][[i]]-Table[15*(k/n),{k,0,n}][[j]]),Not[i==j]},{1,i == j}}],{j,1,Length[Table[15*(k/n),{k,0,n}]]}],{i,1,Length[Table[15*(k/n),{k,0,n}]]}];`

Or in math because that code looks unreadable:

$$p(x,n):=\left\{ \sum^{n}_{i=0}\left( f(x_i)\left(\prod_{j\neq i}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j} \right) \right) : i,j\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}_{n} \ \ and\ \ \left\{x_i \right\}_{i=0}^{n}= \frac{15*i}{n} \right\}$$

I want to export this as a gif up to $n=20$. Unfortunately, I get `$Aborted` around $n=16$.

[image: Exported .gif file]

So now my question: Is there any way I can get Mathematica to not abort?

As always, I appreciate any and all help.

EDIT: I received a comment to include all my code so below is the code I excluded initially:

`f[x_]=x*Sin[x^(1.5)];`
`Export[“coolthing.gif”,Manipulate[Plot[{f[x],p[x,n]},{x,0,15}],{n,1,20}],”GIF”];`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the definition `f`, and the command that aborts.

Comment: @user293787 As requested, see the edit at the bottom of the post.

Comment: I think it would be polite to warn users when a computation takes a long time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

[image]

Using the following code below. Btw, there are better ways to make animated gif files from Manipulate, by saving into a table each frame, then export these frames one by one at the end. You can also have more control on time between frames. If you search this site, you will see examples.

It now also runs faster, since the functions are defined to take in numeric arguments. On my PC this finished in about 3 minutes.

I also added `SetOptions[$FrontEnd,DynamicEvaluationTimeout->60]`  just in case you need more than 6 seconds, but it probably not needed now. Also it is good to add `TrackedSymbols :> {n}, SynchronousUpdating -> False, ContinuousAction -> False` so I added these also.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 60]
p[x_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ] := 
  Sum[f[Table[15*(k/n), {k, 0, n}][[i]]]*
    Product[Piecewise[{{(x - 
           Table[15*(k/n), {k, 0, n}][[j]])/(Table[
             15*(k/n), {k, 0, n}][[i]] - 
           Table[15*(k/n), {k, 0, n}][[j]]), Not[i == j]}, {1, 
        i == j}}], {j, 1, Length[Table[15*(k/n), {k, 0, n}]]}], {i, 1,
     Length[Table[15*(k/n), {k, 0, n}]]}];

f[x_?NumericQ] := x*Sin[x^(15/10)];

Export["coolthing.gif", Manipulate[
  Grid[{{Row["n=", n]},
    {Plot[{f[x], p[x, n]}, {x, 0, 15}]}}
   ],
  {n, 1, 20}, TrackedSymbols :> {n}, SynchronousUpdating -> False, 
  ContinuousAction -> False
  ],
 "GIF"]
```

**Update**

Here is a version for $n=40$. It took 30 minutes on my PC and I had to increase `SetOptions[$FrontEnd,DynamicEvaluationTimeout->200]` also

[image]

```
Export["coolthing.gif", Manipulate[
  Grid[{{Row[{"n=", n}]},
    {Plot[{f[x], p[x, n]}, {x, 0, 15}]}}
   ],
  {n, 1, 40}, TrackedSymbols :> {n}, SynchronousUpdating -> False, 
  ContinuousAction -> False
  ],
 "GIF"]
```

**Update**

per comments, made $n$ integer values and fixed the vertical scale to some values. OP can decide better what these should be.

```
Export["coolthing.gif",
 Manipulate[
  Grid[{{Row[{"n=", n}]},
    {Plot[{f[x], p[x, n]},
      {x, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-40, 40}}]}}
   ],
  {{n, 1, "n"}, 1, 40, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  TrackedSymbols :> {n},
  SynchronousUpdating -> False,
  ContinuousAction -> False
  ],
 "GIF"]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe fix the range of the y-axis to make it look more peaceful?

Comment: Also, maybe restrict `n` to be an integer?

Comment: @user293787 fyi, updated. OP can better fine tune these things as I was just using their code as is.

Comment: I think it looks better this way. Cannot upvote again since already did earlier ;-)

Comment: @user293787 the vertical scale can go as high as many thousands and then the original plot can no longer be seen so I set it at -40..40.  I do not know anything about what the code is doing, other than it is very slow.

Comment: Wow! You're like an actual wizard with Mathematica! For future reference, how do I better format my post? My code text is all black, yours is orange and green.
But thank you so much for your time!

Comment: @Chloe For syntax highlighting see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You can also click "Edit" on Nasser's answer and see how it was written (but do not actually edit it since there is no good reason in this case!). Btw, if you like this answer, please officially accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left, it should then turn green.

Comment: @Nasser As a closing note, the purpose of the code is to show how an interpolating polynomial better approximates a curve as you increase the number of data points (implying also the degree of the polynomial). I want it exported to a GIF file so that it is interesting, and fast, to show to others. Purely recreational.